# What happens when alternate declaration of Strict pragmas in perl script?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Iam new to perl and trying out a sample code for my project.
What happens when i write a code as given below to enable strict pragmas in perl.

use strict;

....... #Source Code
.......

no strict "vars";

....... #source code

use strict                   **#do all strict pragmas enabled until the next pragma     definition ?**

......#Source Code

no strict "subs";             **#do Only subs strict pragma is disabled and others enabled from here onwards?**

...........

**Can i embed use Strict Pragma declarations in between source code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `perldoc strict`:

> If no import list is supplied, all
>   possible restrictions are assumed.

You can change things to be strict about ("subs", "vars", and "refs") anytime.

Answer (score 2):

`use strict` is lexically scoped, which means it will stay in effect "until the end of the enclosing block, file, or eval (whichever comes first)."

Answer (score 2):

For what it’s worth, I think it’s best to isolate the pragma changes using scope:

```
use strict;

{
    no strict;
    local $foo = 1;
}

local $bar = 1;
```

This blows up on setting `bar`, but not on `foo`.